# Why does the facebook like count for my webpage not match the facebook page for that webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-like

I used the facebook generated code at `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like` to display a like button on my website.

Javascript:

```
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-ref="https://facebook.com/mybusinesspage" data-send="false" data-width="100">
<div class="fb-root"></div>
```

But its showing 10 likes when my business facebook page itself has 200 likes.  When I clicked on the like button on the website page, the user is showing he liked the website address of the page INSTEAD of the facebook business page likes.
Is there something I am doing incorrectly in my code?

Comment: The Facebook handles with the page by url. So verify if the url is exactly the same of the page with 200 likes.

Comment: Verified that the number is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook considers your website and your Facebook page as completely separate entities. If you want to display your 200 likes then you will need to generate a new Facebook Like button code with your Facebook page URL rather than your actual .com website.

Comment: I changed the attribute `data-ref` to equal `facebook.com/mybusinesspage` but its still showing a like count that doesn't match the facebook page's likes.

Answer (score 0):

That's may be facebook error. You should report to facebook.